# Entity Framework select few fields from navigation property object

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a simple query:

```
var car = CarRepository.GetById(1);
var engine = new EngineDto
{
    Prop1 = car.Engine.Prop1,
    Prop2 = car.Engine.Prop2,
    Prop3 = car.Engine.Prop3,
    Prop4 = car.Engine.Prop4
}
```

The issue is the Engine model has more then 50 columns and when I try to get value of Engine model property Entity Framework generate query

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM Engine WHERE ID = <id>
```

Is there any way to create query for getting only few fields?

Comment: if your repository would return IQueryable<Car> instead of Car it would be possible with simple Select, otherwise no.

Comment: It returns IQueryable, but cast to DTO occurs in extension method

Comment: At `CarRepository.GetById` you should add **Include**: `return db.Cars.Where(x => x.Id == Id).Include(x => x.Engine).First()`

Comment: You don't understand my question. Engine model already included with Lazy loading.

Comment: @Maks show me your CarRepository, what does GetById does, in ideal world you should be able to call on Car table Car.Include(x => x.Engine).Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => { Prop1 = x.Engine.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Engine.Prop2, Prop3 = x.Engine.Prop3, Prop4 = x.Engine.Prop4 }).Single(); so only necessary fields will be fetched not all columns.

Comment: @kriss I able to create query to select needed properties direct in Car repository ,but we use Vehicle repository to get global Vehicle object and then cast it in different types. Some types haven't Engines. Only when Vehicle has Engine, I try to get Engine properties. In casting step I work with entity not with query.

Comment: @Maks you can use Linq OfType to filter to specific type, hard to help you without seeing all code

Comment: @kriss I know how to get needed props using IQueryable, it's pretty easy, I'm not a jun. In my case I should work with already selected entity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way: don't fetch the complete entity, but use Enumerable.Select to fetch only the data you plan to use.

For this your CarRepository would need a function that return `IEnumerable<Car>` (or similar IQueryable)

In two steps:

```
EngineDto engine = CarRepository.QueryCars() // function to fetch IEnumerable<Car>
    .Where(car => car.Id == 1)
    .Select(car => new EngineDto
    {
        Prop1 = car.Engine.Prop1,
        Prop2 = car.Engine.Prop2,
        Prop3 = car.Engine.Prop3,
        Prop4 = car.Engine.Prop4,
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

If the designer of the CarRepository didn't provide a function that would return a sequence of Cars, then obviously he thought that no one would ever want it. But I'm pretty sure the CarRepository has a function to "fetch all cars"

By the way, as transferring the data from the database to your local process is usually the slower part of your processing, it is always wise to transfer as little data as possible. Try to avoid transferring properties that you didn't plan to use.

Comment: thank you for reply. Look at my last question comment

Comment: @Maks that's the way you should do it, if you have already entity "myCar", you should change Where to .Where(car => car.Id == myCar.Id)

Comment: @kriss, I clarify my question spacial for you. Do you know, how to get few navigation object properties from ALREADY SELECTED entity?

Comment: @Maks hmm I do not know the way, it would be nice if LINQ Select would work on single object :) however if you have your entity fetched you still can fetch only Engine properties like Harald show you

Comment: Linq select on single object? That is just projection where you create one new object of a class and fill the properties with values you fetch from the other class. Like: OtherClass X = new OtherClass() {Prop1 = thisClass.ValueA, Prop2 = thisClass.ValueB, ...};

Comment: Could someone help me with a related question, please? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317150/what-is-a-correct-way-to-select-a-property-of-optional-navigation-property-in-en) it is.