# What is a correct way to select a property of optional navigation property in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, select, null, navigation-properties

What is a correct way to select a property of optional navigation property entity framework?

I am concerned that in case the navigation property will be null, then the error will be thrown when I try to access its (optional navigation property`s) property.

Here is what I tried:

```
return await this.relatedCasesRepository
                    .GetAll()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(rc => rc.FirstCaseId == caseId || rc.SecondCaseId == caseId)
                    .Select(rc => new RelatedCaseInfoDto
                    {
                        FirstCaseId = rc.FirstCaseId,
                        FirstCaseName = rc.FirstCase.Name,
                        SecondCaseId = rc.SecondCaseId,
                        SecondCaseName = rc.SecondCase.Name,
                        CaseRelationTypeId = rc.CaseRelationTypeId,
                        CaseRelationTypeName = rc.CasesRelationType?.Name,
                        Id = rc.Id
                    })
                    .ToArrayAsync();
```

The code: `rc.CasesRelationType?.Name` produces an error:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagation operator.

Does that mean that I should perform a second request to get all the properties of the optional navigation property? Or is there a way to query the optional navigation property`s property in case the optional navigation property is not null and return null otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a conditional operator?

```
CaseRelationTypeName = (rc.CasesRelationType != null) ? rc.CasesRealtionType.Name : null;
```

Comment: It depends on whether your query is `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`. An IQueryable holds an Expression, and a Provider. The Expression represents the query. The Provider knows who must execute the query, usually a database management system. The Provider translates the Expression into language that the DBMS understands and executes the query. Providers can't translate everything. If your provider can't, you'll see this as soon as you execute the query, using ToList, or foreach etc.

Comment: How could I check whether or not my provider supports the ternary operator in the `Select` clause (meaning that it can translate it to an SQL an execute on DB side)? How can I even check what provider I am using? :)

Comment: Just execute the statement (= ToList, foreach, etc) if not supported you'll get an exception. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (entity framework)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)